# Object instances in App Engine

Tags: oop, google-app-engine

I am developing a site using App Engine and Webapp2.

I understand the concepts of OO and more or less how they are applied in Python. However I am confused about how App Engine uses OO. When an instance of my app is created, is one instance of each class created and re-used for each user? Or are separate instances created for each user? This will decide whether I should use instance or class variables.

So to be even more specific, when should I use self. variables (instance variables) and when should I leave out self. (class variables)?

Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 3):

I would separate the concepts of object-orientation (OO) and request handling. First and foremost, App Engine is based on a request-driven model. A request is the base for most actions triggered on App Engine.

Second of all, be aware of the differences between an App Engine instance[0], which is like a container for you application and provided by the App Engine infrastructure, and an webapp2.WSGIApplication[1], which is an object instance of a class you defined.

To simplify things, I assume your app only has 1 webapp2.WSGIApplication . Now let's start with the first request your application gets. Before that, nothing of your app exists, except the code and configuration available on App Engine machines. Once the request reaches App Engine, a new App Engine instance[0] is created. Once the App Engine instance is in place and set up, it will instantiate a webapp2.WSGIApplication instance[1]. Now you have both relevant "instances" in place, the object being a part of the container. Next, the incoming request is routed to your webapp2.WSGIApplication instance which will handle the request according to the implementation you have done.

The App Engine system will create new App Engine instances for you dependening on the load. If a single instance is not able to handle all the requests that come in, it will create a new instance(first [0], then [1] within the former) and spread the load. If that's still not enough, a third instance is created and so on. The same is true if load decreases. If you application is currently running on 3 instances, but 2 would be enough to handle the load, 1 instance will be killed. In addition, you don't know which particular instance will handle which request.

And this leads us to your second question, should you depend on instance variables. Because App Engine creates and kills instances as it seems appropriate and you don't know which instance handles a request, you should always assume instances to be stateless. While it is not always the case, potentially every request can be handled by a completely new instance.

If you need to have state, use memcache (volatile) or datastore (persistent) or some other data backend (blobstore, files API, and so on).

[0] https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances

[1] http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/app.html

PS: people do use instance memory to optimize requests, but beginners who start to learn about App Engine should consider this an advanced technique.

Comment: Hi schuppe. I just realised I never thanked you for your answer. So, thanks a lot! It was a very clear, succinct answer to my question.